# Second controller in Angular not prompting FB login

Tags: facebook, node.js, angularjs, firebase

I have used angular a little before, but this is my first time setting it up.

I am trying to get Firebase Simple Login working with Angular, Node, and Express. My goal is to have it so when a user clicks a login button, they sign in to the app with their facebook (will later add Twitter and Email+Password).

The problem is, when I click the login, an event is triggered from the main controller for the page (and alert), but not the controller I set. I have tried adding/changing the controller in the app.config() section, moving names around, using past code, starting from scratch, following countless tutorials, and even did a simple base case to have a console.log. Still nothing and I am probably completely misunderstanding things, but how do I get this working?

Script files:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', 
    ['ngRoute', 'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'firebase', 'ngTouch']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
      controller: 'MyCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});

var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

controllers.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFire',
  function($scope, angularFire) {

    var users = new Firebase('https://test.firebaseio.com');
    //angularFire(users, $scope, "users");s

    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('sdfiojdsfdsf');
                alert('dsifjosdf');
            });

}]);

controllers.controller("MyAuthCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$firebaseAuth",
  function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com");
    $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
    // $scope.auth.user will be `null` until the user logs in.

    $rootScope.$on("$firebaseAuth:login", function(evt, user) {
      console.log("User " + user.id + " successfully logged in!");
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$firebaseAuth:logout", function(evt) {
      console.log("User logged out!");
    });

}]);
```

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyAuthCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="fblogin" ng-click="auth.$login('facebook')">Login Facebook</a></li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="auth.logout()">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be mixing `angularFire` with `$firebaseAuth`. If you're using AngularFire 0.5, the services are named `$firebase` and `$firebaseAuth`. Secondly it's best to create only a single instance of `$firebaseAuth` in a service of your own instead of creating one in every controller. Then you call `$login()` from your own service and use the `$rootScope` to let various controllers know that the login succeeded using events.

Comment: Okay, everything seems to be functional. I am using angularFire 0.5 and have $firebase and $firebaseAuth set up. But now I get this error:
`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'has' at Object.AngularFireAuth (https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.js:512:22)` and I am still unable to log in.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Updating to 1.2 might help. If you want to use 1.0.7 specifically, you can use the latest version of angularfire (0.6) that will be released sometime today that fixes this issue.

Comment: Going with something different now, but thanks. I will try that out when I can.